# Data gets change when ng-model=data.property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-change

Here is the code snippet that I have been tried

```
 <div  class="row list-group-item" ng-repeat="prop in Task.taskArray">
                                        <div style="height: 20px" class="col-xs-2">
                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="prop.ID" ng-change="changeInTask(prop.rID,prop)"  >
                                        </div>
```

In my .js file when I print the value of `prop.ID` it gives true/ false value.

The original value has been replaced. Why?

Comment: Because a checkbox is expecting a boolean?

Comment: OK. Please provide a solution.I have needed a unique id to identify each checkbox.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="prop.value" name="{{prop.ID}}" />`?

Comment: 'value' property of 'prop' object will be changed. I have asked to prevent it!!

Comment: Then it's extremely unclear what you're trying to do. Why do you use `ngModel` if you don't want its behaviour?

Comment: I have used ng-model to identify whether the checkbox checked of unchecked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my problem like this

```
<div  class="row list-group-item" ng-repeat="prop in Task.taskArray track by $index">
                                        <div style="height: 20px" class="col-xs-2">
                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="prop.ID" ng-change="changeInTask(prop[$index],prop)"  >
                                        </div>
```